# WCF Request Interceptors - Not supported any more?

Tags: .net, wcf, authorization

I've been trying to get some custom authentication code for my WCF service and found that one way to this would be through a RequestInterceptor in the [REST Starter Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee391967.aspx). However, since the article was published, it seems that Microsoft has done some internal refactoring and Microsoft.ServiceModels.Web was moved to System.ServiceModels.Web. This namespace does not have a RequestInterceptor class in it and I can't find any references to it in the docs.

Does anyone know what the best practice is to do this? I need to add authentication / authorization to a part of my API.

Thanks,
Teja

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you to take a look at 
IDispatchMessageInspector and [IClientMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.beforesendrequest.aspx)